# Getting Duplicate Values in Output for PostgreSQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I executed the below query in PostgreSQL, but I'm getting duplicate values

**Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.icon_url, t.text
FROM media_table AS m,
     text_table AS t
WHERE m.media_id in (SELECT DISTINCT media_id from service_table
                     where service_id in('01','02'))
  AND t.text_id in (select DISTINCT text_id from service_table
                    where service_id in ('01','02'))
```

**Output:**

```
"Icon_url 1" | "text 1"

"Icon_url 2" | "text 2"

"Icon_url 1" | "text 1"

"Icon_url 2" | "text 2"
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: I find it hard to believe SELECT DISTINCT returns duplicates. Can you create a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12

Comment: Note that your two subqueries may give result from different rows. Perhaps you want `where (m.media_id, t.text_id) in (select media_id, text_id from service_table where service_id in ('01','02'))`

Comment: Why don't you have a join condition between `media_table` and `text_table`? I wonder if you intended to write:  `from service_table st join media_table mt on st.media_id = mt.media_id join text_table tt on tt.text_id = st.text_id where st.service_id in (...)`?

Comment: Your results have no duplicates.  Your question is unclear.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do would all help.